# OpenVPN Ubuntu Server Routing Problems No Internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I'm running OpenVPN on Ubuntu 15.04.

When I connect to the server, I can connect and authenticate correctly (I use PAM auth because I'm lazy). Once connected I can't ping the server or access the internet except when I use my servers public IP then I get my website in a fashion because it can't load the style scripts and javascript in etc...

I'm pretty sure this is a iptables problem...

My goal is that clients can talk to each other and talk to the server while having unrestricted access to the internet.

I can post config files if needed.

Many thanks,
Zac

Answer (score 0):

sorry, this is not an answer but my reputation is to low to add a comment on your post. Please post your OpenVPN server config and all your iptables rules. (iptables -L -v and iptables -L -v -t nat)

My first guess would be that you have to add a SNAT or MASQUERADE in your iptables POSTROUTING chain.

Example: (10.8.0.0/24 is your VPN network, eth0 is your network interface connected to the internet)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Also you would have to allow traffic in your FORWARDING chain.

Comment: Hello, please find outputs http://pastebin.com/2rktvdmu I have tried adding some iptable rules but no luck so i flushed the (-F) and rebooted. Im running it on a vps so im guessing i need to use venet0 not eth0? Ignore all the other rules in the iptables, im running vestacp and need them for that. thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: You can use the ifconfig command to see your network interfaces, but you're right, on a vps its often called venet0. You should replace the interface parameter within your iptables rules then. (Please also remove your public IP from the pastebin file)

Comment: after running your command above and changing the interface, i get this back: "iptables v1.4.21: Can't use -i with POSTROUTING

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information."

Comment: Sorry, it's -o venet0 (?) because its the outgoing interface. My bad. 
Where did you get this line in your server config from? 'push "route 0.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"' Doesn't make that much sense, does it? If you want to reach the local subnet of your server from the client, you have to put it in this line.

Comment: tried that command and still no luck. I also removed the push "route 0.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 from my config and still no luck...

Comment: My only idea is the following:
It would probably make sense to save your firewall settings, flush it and set all policies to accept and reload after the debugging. If you have cleared iptables, add only the POSTROUTING (MASQUERADE) rule and test those pings:

Can you ping the server with his OpenVPN IP (probably 10.8.0.1)?
Can you ping the server with his local network ip (if available, 192.168.x..x or something)? You would have to use the push route line in the config)
Can you ping the server with his public ip and can you ping google or something.

Comment: Please stop having a discussion in comments. Take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=serverfault.com) if you're going to continue to discuss things.

Comment: Flushed nat table. And showing info on that (-S) shows how prerouting, postrouting and output are all accepted. Added that one rule and after connecting I can't ping 10.8.0.1, but I can ping my servers public IP address and can't ping Google at 8.8.8.8

Comment: Found the problem with my server. In my client config I missed out `comp-lzo` but in my server config I had it. Thanks all for help. I didn't think something like that would make such a difference